# VueJS - Adjusting property from method does not update the view

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the Vue Multiselect component, along with a list that displays suggested items.

I've basically got

```
selectedItems: []
allItems: []

onSelectOfItem(item) {
   item.selected = true;
}
```

My HTML has the `@select="onSelectOfItem"` event which fires when multiselect picks an item, and it passes in the item.

I've also got a list of suggested items thats like

```
<li v-for="item in allItems" v-if="!item.selected"></li>
```

However when the `onSelectOfItem` method fires and I assign `selected = true` the `v-for` I have does not hide the item, however if I use the vue debug tools and inspect the data `selected` is set to `false`

If i add a `@click="onSelectOfItem(item)"` to the repeater, it works fine.

Id expect that changing the value on the object would update throughout, I'm from an Angular background which passes everything by reference, so no matter where i update `item.selected` from the whole UI will be in sync.

Why is the UI not reacting to the change within the object?? and how can I fix.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: As it happens, I've realised I was doing something that wasn't needed anyway, so I'm not actually having to solve this problem anymore, however I guess my question still stands, but it might be more of a conflict between the multiselect component than anything!